# Linq query which has a non db object within

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5

I have multiple View Model classes that get data from the database using Linq (DBContext classes have a similar structure but with more fields)

I am lacking knowledge to get data from one class object because that is contained within a wrapper class that does not have a corresponding db object.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions on this.

Here are the class structures:

```
public class TopLevelViewModel
{
    public TopLevelID  { get; set; }
    public TopLevelTitle  { get; set; }
    public List<SecondLevelViewModel> SeconLevel { set; get; }

    public TopLevelViewModel()
    {
           Inner = new List<SecondLevelViewModel>();
    }
}

public class SecondLevelViewModel
{
    public SecondLevelID  { get; set; }
    public SecondLevelTitle  { get; set; }
    public TopLevelID  { get; set; }
    public WrapperViewModel  { get; set; }
}   

public class InnerViewModel
{
    public InnerID  { get; set; }
    public InnerTitle  { get; set; }
    public SecondLevelID  { get; set; }
}

public class WrapperViewModel
{
    public List<InnerViewModel> Inner { set; get; }

    public WrapperViewModel()
    {
        Inner = new List<InnerViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Linq query to get data for the above db objects:

```
List<TopLevelViewModel> data = null;
data = db.TopLevel.Where(t => t.TopLevelID == URLTopLevelID)
                  .Select(t => new TopLevelViewModel()
                                   {
                                      TopLevelID = t.TopLevelID,
                                      TopLevelTitle = t.TopLevelTitle,
                                      SeconLevel = db.SecondLevel.Where(s => s.TopLevelID == t.TopLevelID)
          .Select(s => new SecondLevelViewModel()
                           {
                                SecondLevelID = s.SecondLevelID, 
                                SeconLevelTitle = s.SeconLevelTitle,              
                                WrapperViewModel = ???
                           }).ToList<SecondLevelViewModel>()
                }).ToList < TopLevelViewModel();
```

Query to get Inner object data:

```
db.Inner.Where(i => i.SecondLevelID == s.SecondLevelID)
        .Select(i => new InnerViewModel()
                         {
                             InnerID  = i.InnerID,
                             InnerTitle = i.InnerTitle
                         }).ToList<InnerViewModel>()
```

Question: how do I incorporate the above inner query to be part of `WrapperViewModel` class and have that in the main Linq query as a single query?

`WrapperViewModel` does not have a DB object but it is kind of a wrapper class to `InnerViewModel` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Hope it will be useful to someone. If there are any ideas/suggestions please share!

The single query would be:

```
       List<TopLevelViewModel> data = null ;
        data = db.TopLevel.Where(t => t.TopLevelID == URLTopLevelID).Select(t => new TopLevelViewModel()
                {
                    TopLevelID = t.TopLevelID,
        TopLevelTitle = t.TopLevelTitle,
                    SeconLevel = db.SecondLevel.Where(s => s.TopLevelID == t.TopLevelID).Select(s => new SecondLevelViewModel()
                    {
                        SecondLevelID = s.SecondLevelID, 
            SeconLevelTitle = s.SeconLevelTitle,              
                        WrapperViewModel = new WrapperViewModel { Inner = 
                                        db.Inner.Where(i => i.SecondLevelID == s.SecondLevelID).Select(i => new InnerViewModel()
                                            {
                                               InnerID  = i.InnerID,
                       InnerTitle = i.InnerTitle
                                            }).ToList<InnerViewModel>() 
                    }).ToList<SecondLevelViewModel>()
                }).ToList < TopLevelViewModel();
```